# Django TypeError on every page

Tags: python, django

I haven't touched the code on my app in weeks but i'm suddenly getting this exact same TypeError on every page, including Admin pages.

The last thing to happen was an update on a model to change a ForeignKey field, but I don't feel the two are related

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://10.0.0.161:8001/admin/

Django Version: 1.9.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'phones',
 'jobs',
 'profiles',
 'freelancers',
 'stock',
 'finance']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'profiles.middleware.UpdateLastActivityMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/studioxag/Documents/repos/telephones/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/studioxag/Documents/repos/telephones/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  172.                     response = response.render()

File "/Users/studioxag/Documents/repos/telephones/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Users/studioxag/Documents/repos/telephones/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  137.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/Users/studioxag/Documents/repos/telephones/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/studioxag/Documents/repos/telephones/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  204.                 with context.bind_template(self):

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py" in __enter__
  17.             return self.gen.next()

File "/Users/studioxag/Documents/repos/telephones/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in bind_template
  260.             updates.update(processor(self.request))

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: too bad you forgot to share the code

Comment: I didn't know which bits of code to share as the error was on every page. Would I have linked you every views.py in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by looking through some of my own context processors. I had one function that was returning None on a request (after changing an entry and having an empty queryset as a result).